# Problem concerning isometries

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, isometry

Let $$f(x) = Q(x) + v\quad\text{and}\quad g(x) = P(x)  + w$$ be 2 isometries of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Write the composition $g ◦ f$ in the form $U(x) + z$, with $Q, P, U \in O(n)$ and $v, w, z \in \mathbb{R^n}$

**Attempt at solving the question:**

$$g ◦ f = g(f(x)) = g(Q(x)+v) = P(Q(x)+v)+w = P(Q(x)) + (v +w),$$

so we have $U(x) = P(Q(x))$ and $v+w = z$.

Is that the right approach to solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is fine, you just messed up in the end:

$$g(f(x)) = g(Qx+ v) = P(Qx+v) + w = PQx + Pv + w,$$so $U = PQ$ and $z = Pv + w $.